# How to prevent extension suggestion for just one specific extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to prevent VSCode from suggesting a particular extension (`ms-vscode.makefile-tools` in this case). Is this possible?

Note that I do not want to turn off suggestions completely, I just do not want this particular extension to be suggested.

This is in the context of dev containers, so I need something that can be put into `.vcode/settings.json` or similar.

I did try to reply to the suggestion with "Do not suggest this extension again" (or some such) but I could not find where this setting was saved.